# separating v-if and v-for Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, v-for

I have read that we shouldn't put v-if and v-for together in vuejs. I've also got an error in the IDE. How am I suppose to separate the v-if and v-for in my code so that it follows the style guide?

```
<div
        v-for="(value, key, index) in items"
        v-if="value.level === undefined || value.level < level"
        :key="key"
      >
```

level is a computed value too

```
computed: {
    level() {
      return (
         user.access>3
      );
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use invisible wrapper `(<template>)` element with v-if. Benefit of using this is `template won't render` until condition met. You can read more about template [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt)

Example:

```
<div v-for="(value, key, index) in items" :key="key">
  <template v-if="value.level === undefined || value.level < level"> // It won't render until v-if = true
   ....
```

Answer (score 3):

put the `v-if` directive in a virtual element `template` :

```
<div   v-for="(value, key, index) in items" :key="key">
   <template v-if="value.level === undefined || value.level < level">
    ....
```

Comment: Great use of `<template>`, I haven't seen it documented this way.

Comment: Yes they put v-for inside template but the template couldn't be keyed

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a bunch of empty divs on the dom, filter it.

```
computed: {
   filtered_items: function() {
     return this.items.filter(v => typeof v.level === 'undefined' || v.level < this.level)
   }
},
```

Then use `filtered_items` instead of `items` in the v-for

Can also do inline:

`v-for="item in items.filter(v => typeof v.level === 'undefined' || v.level < level)"`

Comment: The first suggestion is the best because the computed value is cached and the template is not messed with a lot of logic

Comment: yeah is just an option to do inline, though is still the same logic which is already in the view is just on the one line instead of 2. though I think might be a bug in the OP's `v.level < level` as level from the computed is boolean

Comment: although according to the style guides, the computed one seems right but it isn't working on my app

Comment: it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null"

Comment: `items` should be set to an array in data